# select [CAR] based on [FEATURE]s -- all or nothing

Tags: sql, database, select

Currently, I have 2 tables with the following data:

```
[CAR]
Honda
Ford
Mazda

[FEATURE]
CD player
Sunroof
Leather
```

In another table, I store their relationships.

```
[CAR_FEATURE]
Honda    | CD Player
Mazda    | CD Player
Mazda    | Sunroof
Mazda    | Leather
```

My problem is... I need to select the **[CAR]** that has all the **[FEATURE]** I am looking for -- all or nothing.

For example, if I am looking for a car with a **CD Player**, **Sunroof**, AND **Leather**, then it would output Mazda.

If I am looking for a car with a **CD Player**, then it would ONLY output Honda.

If I am looking for a car with a **Sunroof**, then it would output nothing because I am searching for all or nothing.

---

How would I write the query statement in SQL for this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variation of T McKeown's query will get you a car matching all the features exactly, not more or less:

```
SELECT CAR
FROM CAR_FEATURE
GROUP BY CAR
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN FEATURE IN ('CD Player', 'Sunroof', 'Leather') 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE -1 
           END) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
SELECT CAR
FROM CAR_FEATURE
WHERE FEATURE IN ('CD Player', 'Sunroof', 'Leather')
GROUP BY CAR
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Just adjust the `HAVING` clause based on the features, you could pass in a CSV list of features and create a TABLE variable table that has all the features so the query could be like this:

```
DECLARE @LIST_OF_FEATURES TABLE(FEATURE VARCHAR(50))

--INSERT INTO THE @LIST_OF_FEATURES USING THE FORXML

SELECT CAR
FROM CAR_FEATURE
WHERE FEATURE IN (SELECT FEATURE FROM @LIST_OF_FEATURES)
GROUP BY CAR
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @LIST_OF_FEATURES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact table structure, so I will improvise with field names. I hope it's clear from context:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CAR c
JOIN CAR_FEATURE cf ON (c.id = cf.car_id)
JOIN FEATURE f ON (f.id = cf.feature_id)
LEFT JOIN FEATURE f2 ON (f2.id = cf.feature_id
      AND f2.id NOT IN (<list of feature ids>))
WHERE f.id IN (<same list of features ids as above>)
      AND f2.id IS NULL
```

This would bring the cars that have the features you want, but that do not have any other features.

Concrete example. Suppose your feature id are the names (not a great idea, but good for the example), then you would write:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CAR c
JOIN CAR_FEATURE cf ON (c.id = cf.car_id)
JOIN FEATURE f ON (f.id = cf.feature_id)
LEFT JOIN FEATURE f2 ON (f2.id = cf.feature_id
      AND f2.id NOT IN ('CD Player','Sunroof'))
WHERE f.id IN ('CD Player','Sunroof')
      AND f2.id IS NULL
```

Hope this helps!